# Pygame runs slow after excecuting program

Tags: python, pygame, python-3.2

Im making a space invaders type of game and I have a function called bulletboost where I load an image and paste it onto the screen at random x and y points.

```
def bulletboost():
        fastbullets.append((randint(50 ,800)))
        fastbullets.append((randint(0,100)))
        bul=image.load("image/bullet.png").convert()
        gameDisplay.blit(bul,(fastbullets[0],fastbullets[1]))
```

And here is the whole code to the game(VERY LONG):

```
import sys
from pygame import *
from math import *
from random import *
import random
import math
init()

display_width = 1000
display_height = 700

shipx = 350
shipy = 550

current_level=0

spawner=0

asteroids=[]
astroidX=randint(0,800)
astroidY=randint(50,500)
astroidY_change=0

counter=0

alien=[]
aliencounter=0
enemy_y =0
enemy_x=0

fastbullets=[]

gameover=False

alienbullets=[]
w=[0,3]

gameDisplay = display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

screen=display.set_mode((1000,700))



white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)


red = (200,0,0)
light_red = (255,0,0)

yellow = (200,200,0)
light_yellow = (255,255,0)

green = (34,177,76)
light_green = (0,255,0)

blue = (0,0,255)

clock = time.Clock()

explosion_sound = mixer.Sound('./sounds/boom.wav')
bullet_sound = mixer.Sound('./sounds/shot1.wav')

bg_sound = mixer.Sound('./sounds/bgmusic1.ogg')

smallfont = font.SysFont("comicsansms", 25)
medfont = font.SysFont("comicsansms", 50)
largefont = font.SysFont("comicsansms", 85)
xlargefont = font.SysFont("Girassol", 100)

textx = 8
texty = 40


bg_imgs = ['./image/bg_big.png',
        './image/seamless_space.png',
        './image/space3.jpg']
bg_move_dis = 0
bg_1 = image.load(bg_imgs[0]).convert()
bg_2 = image.load(bg_imgs[1]).convert()
bg_3 = image.load(bg_imgs[2]).convert()

Score_1 = 200
Score_2 = 200

if (Score_1 + Score_2) < 500:
    background = bg_1
elif (Score_1 + Score_2) < 1500:
    background = bg_2
else:
    background = bg_3



v=[0,-5]#horiz and vertical speed of the bullet
#print(ets)


bullets=[]#empty list for bullets

astroid=image.load("image/meteorBrown_med1.png").convert_alpha()

alienspaceship=image.load("image/ufo.png").convert_alpha()

def show_score(x,y):
    score = smallfont.render("Score : " + str(score_value), True, light_yellow)
    screen.blit(score,(x,y))
def show_lives(x,y):
    lives = smallfont.render("Lives : " + str(livesr), True, green)
    screen.blit(lives,(x,y))
def show_level(x,y):
    level = smallfont.render("Level : " + str(current_level), True, blue)
    screen.blit(level,(x,y))

def text_objects(text, color,size = "small"):

    if size == "small":
        textSurface = smallfont.render(text, True, color)
    if size == "medium":
        textSurface = medfont.render(text, True, color)
    if size == "large":
        textSurface = largefont.render(text, True, color)
    if size == "xlarge":
        textSurface = xlargefont.render(text, True, color)

    return textSurface, textSurface.get_rect()

def text_to_button(msg, color, buttonx, buttony, buttonwidth, buttonheight, size = "small"):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg,color,size)
    textRect.center = ((buttonx+(buttonwidth/2)), buttony+(buttonheight/2))
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def message_to_screen(msg,color, y_displace = 0, size = "small"):
    textSurf, textRect = text_objects(msg,color,size)
    textRect.center = (int(display_width / 2), int(display_height / 2)+y_displace)
    gameDisplay.blit(textSurf, textRect)

def button(text, x, y, width, height, inactive_color, active_color, action = None):
    cur = mouse.get_pos()
    click = mouse.get_pressed()
    #print(click)
    if x + width > cur[0] > x and y + height > cur[1] > y:
        draw.rect(gameDisplay, active_color, (x,y,width,height))
        if click[0] == 1 and action != None:
            if action == "Quit":
                quit()

            if action == "Play":
                play()
            if action == "Controls":
                control_menu()
            if action == "Back":
                game_intro()
            if action =="Start":
                gameLoop()

    else:
        draw.rect(gameDisplay, inactive_color, (x,y,width,height))

    text_to_button(text,black,x,y,width,height)

def game_intro():
    menu_1 = image.load('./image/menubackground.jpg')
    gameDisplay.blit(menu_1,(0,0))

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for evt in event.get():
                #print(event)
                if evt.type == QUIT:
                    quit()


                if evt.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if evt.key == K_c:
                        intro = False
                    elif evt.key == K_q:

                        quit()



        message_to_screen("Space Heroes!",green,-210,size="xlarge")
        message_to_screen("The objective is to shoot and destroy",white,-30)
        message_to_screen("the enemy ships before they destroy you.",white,10)
        message_to_screen("Defeat all of them to advance to next level!.",white,50)
        message_to_screen("By Wafi Hassan",blue, 110)

        button("Play", 230,500,100,50, green, light_green, action="Play")
        button("Controls", 430,500,100,50, yellow, light_yellow, action="Controls")
        button("Quit", 630,500,100,50, red, light_red, action ="Quit")

        display.update()

        clock.tick(15)



def control_menu():
    menu_1 = image.load('./image/menubackground.jpg')
    gameDisplay.blit(menu_1,(0,0))

    intro = True

    while intro:
        for evt in event.get():
                #print(event)
                if evt.type == QUIT:
                    quit()


                if evt.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if evt.key == K_c:
                        intro = False
                    elif evt.key == K_q:

                        quit()

        message_to_screen("Controls",blue,-210,size="large")
        message_to_screen("SPACE    -    SHOOT",white,-30)
        message_to_screen("A-D   -  Left and Right movement",white,10)

        button("Back", 550,500,100,50, red, light_red, action ="Back")

        display.update()

        clock.tick(15)

def game_over():
    global alien
    global alienbullets
    global livesr
    global score_value
    global shipx
    global shipy
    global current_level
    global aliencounter
    global asteroids
    global bullets
    bullets=[]
    asteroids=[]
    aliencounter=0
    alien=[]
    alienbullets=[]
    livesr=1
    score_value=0
    shipx=350
    shipy=550
    current_level=1
    bg_sound.stop()
    menu_1 = image.load('./image/gameover.jpg').convert_alpha()
    gameDisplay.blit(menu_1,(0,0))

    gameover = True

    while gameover:
        for evt in event.get():
            if evt.type == QUIT:
                gameover=False
                quit()





        button("QUIT", 550,500,100,50, red, light_red, action ="Quit")
        button("RESTART", 310,500,115,50, red, light_red, action ="Start")

        display.update()

        clock.tick(15)




def play():
    display_width = 1000
    display_height = 700
    screen=display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
    running=True
    y=0
    while running:
        for evt in event.get():
            #print(event)
                if evt.type == QUIT:
                    quit()


                if evt.type == KEYDOWN:
                    if evt.key == K_e:
                          gameLoop()

        rel_y = y % bg_3.get_rect().width
        screen.blit(bg_3,(0,rel_y - bg_3.get_rect().width))
        if rel_y < 600:
            screen.blit(bg_3,(0,rel_y))
        y +=1

        message_to_screen("Attention, Fighter! ",blue,-300,size="medium")
        message_to_screen("You have been summoned by our government to protect our planet Kiblar.",white,-210)
        message_to_screen("We are being attacked by incoming enemies from the planet Noxus.",white,-170)
        message_to_screen("You are our only defender left, protect us at all costs!",white,-130)
        message_to_screen("Intelligence reports that there are 2 waves of enemies.",white,-90)
        message_to_screen("After you eliminate them all, they will send their mothership Dengrau.",white,-50)
        message_to_screen("Killing Dengrau will save our existence on galaxy 1029 from the rival planet Noxus.",white,-10)
        message_to_screen("ARE YOU READY TO TAKE THIS CHALLENGE?!",white,130)
        message_to_screen("CLICK [E] TO START!",red,190)


        display.update()

        myclock.tick(120)

    quit()


def enemy_generate(): 

    for i in range(5):
        asteroids.append((randint(50 ,800),randint(0,100)))



def drawScene(screen,sx,sy,bull,alienbull,alien,asteroids):

    lee=image.load("image/laserRed16.png").convert_alpha()
    bt=image.load("image/missile.png").convert_alpha()
##    astrow=image.load("image/meteorBrown_med1.png").convert_alpha
    spaceship=image.load("image/ship.png").convert_alpha()
    screen.blit(spaceship,[sx,sy])  

    for b in bull:
        screen.blit(bt,(b[0],b[1]))#drawing the bullets


    for en in alien:  

        screen.blit(alienspaceship,(en[0],en[1]))


    for a in asteroids:  
        astroid=image.load("image/meteorBrown_med1.png").convert_alpha()
        screen.blit(astroid,(a[0],(a[1]+astroidY_change))) ######################## change


    for eb in alienbull:

        screen.blit(lee,(eb[0],eb[1]))#drawing the bullets       


    display.update()

score_value=0
lives=3
def checkHits(bull,targ,astero,crate):
    global score_value
    global rapidbullet
    for b in bull:# go through each bullet
        for a in astero:
            aliendistance = math.sqrt((math.pow(b[0]-a[0],2)) + (math.pow(b[1]-a[1],2)))
            if aliendistance < 40:
                asteroids.remove(a)
                bull.remove(b)
                explosion_sound.play()
                score_value+=1
                break
        for t in targ: #go through each target
            distance = math.sqrt((math.pow(b[0]-t[0],2)) + (math.pow(b[1]-t[1],2)))
            if distance < 60:
                targ.remove(t)#removes the target
                bull.remove(b)#removes the bullet
                explosion_sound.play()
                score_value += 1
                if score_value==10:
                    level_2()
                elif score_value==30:
                    level_3()
                elif score_value==60:
                    gamefinish()
                break
        for c in crate:
            boxdistance=math.sqrt((math.pow(b[0]-fastbullets[1],2)) + (math.pow(b[1]-fastbullets[0],2)))
            if boxdistance<30: 
                crate.remove(c)
                bull.remove(b)
                explosion_sound.play()
                rapidbullet=20
                break


livesr=1
def checkalienbullets(alienbull):
    global livesr
    global score_value
    for a in alienbull:
        alienbdistance=math.sqrt((math.pow(a[0]-shipx,2)) + (math.pow(a[1]-shipy,2)))
        if alienbdistance<40:
            livesr-=1
            print(livesr)
            if livesr==0:
                game_over()
def bulletboost():
        fastbullets.append((randint(50 ,800)))
        fastbullets.append((randint(0,100)))
        bul=image.load("image/bullet.png").convert()
        gameDisplay.blit(bul,(fastbullets[0],fastbullets[1]))




def moveBullets(bull):
    for b in bull:
        b[0]+=b[2]
        b[1]+=b[3]
        if b[1]>700:#off-screen
            bull.remove(b)

def move_alien_bull(ebull):
    for e in ebull:
        e[0]+=e[2]
        e[1]+=e[3]
        if e[1]>700:#off-screen
            ebull.remove(e)

def level_2():
    global asteroids
    global alien
    global aliencounter
    global alienbullets
    global shipx
    global shipy
    global current_level
    global livesr
    global score_value
    global enemy_y
    global astroidY 
    global astroidY_change
    global bullets
    bullets=[]
    asteriodY_change=0
    alien=[]
    aliencounter=0
    rapidbullet=40
    y=0
    alienbullets=[]
    shipx=350
    shipy=550
    ship_x =0
    ship_y=0 
    current_level+=1
    livesr+=1
    direction= None
    running=True
    function=True
    while running:
        astroidY_change += .5
        #enemy_y += 0
        #global alienbullets
        for evt in event.get():
            if evt.type==QUIT:
                running=False
                quit()
            if evt.type==KEYDOWN:
                if evt.key == K_LEFT:
                    ship_x = -2.5
                if evt.key == K_RIGHT:
                    ship_x = 2.5
##                if evt.key == K_UP: 
##                    ship_y = -2
##                if evt.key == K_DOWN: 
##                    ship_y = 2
            if evt.type==KEYUP:
                if evt.key == K_LEFT or evt.key == K_RIGHT: 
                    ship_x = 0
##                    ship_y = 0

        shipx += ship_x
##        shipy += ship_y 

        if shipx <= 0: 
            shipx = 0
        elif shipx >= 900:
            shipx = 900

##        if shipy <= 0: 
##            shipy = 0
##        elif shipy >= 650:
##            shipy = 650



        # astroid Movement
        astroidY += astroidY_change

        if astroidY_change >=650: 
           astroidY_change =0    


        if rapidbullet<40:
            rapidbullet+=1

        keys=key.get_pressed()       
        if keys[32] and rapidbullet==40:#32 is the space key
            bullet_sound.play()

            bullets.append([shipx,shipy,v[0],v[1]]) 
            rapidbullet=0


        if random.randrange(0,6*20) == 1 and score_value<=30:
            aliencounter+=1
            x= randint(50,700)
            y= randint(0,100)
            alien.append([x,y])
            alienbullets.append([x,y,w[0],w[1]])




        rel_y = y % bg_3.get_rect().width
        screen.blit(bg_3,(0,rel_y - bg_3.get_rect().width))
        if rel_y < 700:
            screen.blit(bg_3,(0,rel_y))
        y +=1

        if enemy_y >= 600: 
           enemy_y = 0

        show_score(textx,texty)
        show_lives(10,70)
        show_level(10,10)
        moveBullets(bullets)
        move_alien_bull(alienbullets)
        checkHits(bullets,alien,asteroids,fastbullets)
        checkalienbullets(alienbullets)
        drawScene(screen,shipx,shipy,bullets,alienbullets,alien,asteroids) 

        display.update()
        myclock.tick(120)

    quit()


def level_3():
    enemy_generate()
    global alien
    global aliencounter
    global alienbullets
    global shipx
    global shipy
    global current_level
    global livesr
    global score_value
    global enemy_y
    global astroidY 
    global astroidY_change
    global bullets
    bullets=[]
    asteriodY_change=0
    alien=[]
    aliencounter=0
    rapidbullet=40
    alienbullets=[]
    y=0
    shipx=350
    shipy=550
    ship_x =0
    ship_y=0 
    current_level+=1
    livesr+=1
    direction= None
    running=True
    function=True
    while running:
        astroidY_change += .5
        #global alienbullets
        for evt in event.get():
            if evt.type==QUIT:
                running=False
                quit()
            if evt.type==KEYDOWN:
                if evt.key == K_LEFT:
                    ship_x = -2.5
                if evt.key == K_RIGHT:
                    ship_x = 2.5
##                if evt.key == K_UP: 
##                    ship_y = -2
##                if evt.key == K_DOWN: 
##                    ship_y = 2
            if evt.type==KEYUP:
                if evt.key == K_LEFT or evt.key == K_RIGHT: 
                    ship_x = 0
##                    ship_y = 0

        shipx += ship_x
##        shipy += ship_y 

        if shipx <= 0: 
            shipx = 0
        elif shipx >= 900:
            shipx = 900

##        if shipy <= 0: 
##            shipy = 0
##        elif shipy >= 650:
##            shipy = 650



        # astroid Movement
        astroidY += astroidY_change

        if astroidY_change >=650: 
           astroidY_change =0    


        if rapidbullet<40:
            rapidbullet+=1

        keys=key.get_pressed()       
        if keys[32] and rapidbullet==40:#32 is the space key
            bullet_sound.play()

            bullets.append([shipx,shipy,v[0],v[1]]) 
            rapidbullet=0


        if random.randrange(0,6*15) == 1 and score_value<=60:
            aliencounter+=1
            x= randint(50,700)
            y= randint(0,100)
            alien.append([x,y])
            alienbullets.append([x,y,w[0],w[1]])




        rel_y = y % bg_3.get_rect().width
        screen.blit(bg_3,(0,rel_y - bg_3.get_rect().width))
        if rel_y < 700:
            screen.blit(bg_3,(0,rel_y))
        y +=1

        if enemy_y >= 600: 
           enemy_y = 0

        show_score(textx,texty)
        show_lives(10,70)
        show_level(10,10)
        moveBullets(bullets)
        move_alien_bull(alienbullets)
        checkHits(bullets,alien,asteroids,fastbullets)
        checkalienbullets(alienbullets)
        drawScene(screen,shipx,shipy,bullets,alienbullets,alien,asteroids) 

        display.update()
        myclock.tick(120)

    quit()

def gamefinish():
    global alien
    global alienbullets
    global livesr
    global score_value
    global shipx
    global shipy
    global current_level
    global aliencounter
    global asteroids
    global bullets
    bullets=[]
    asteroids=[]
    aliencounter=0
    alien=[]
    alienbullets=[]
    livesr=1
    score_value=0
    shipx=350
    shipy=550
    current_level=1
    bg_sound.stop()

    gameDisplay = display.set_mode((1000,700))
    bg_sound.stop()
    over = image.load('./image/gamewon.jpg').convert_alpha()
    gameDisplay.blit(over,(0,0))

    gamewin = True

    while gamewin:
        for evt in event.get():
            if evt.type == QUIT:
                gamewin=False
                quit()





        button("QUIT", 550,500,100,50, red, light_red, action ="Quit")
        button("MENU", 310,500,100,50, red, light_red, action ="Back")


##        texting=medfont.render("Your score:",show_score, True,(0,0,0))
##        gameDisplay.blit(texting,(0,0))


        display.update()

        clock.tick(15)

    print("Your score:", score_value)
    print("Level:", current_level)
    print("Lives Left:", livesr)






myclock=time.Clock()
##y=0

##enemy_generate() 

def gameLoop():
    gameover=False
    livesr=1
    bg_sound.play(-1)
    rapidbullet=40
    y=0
    score=0
    ship_x =0
    ship_y=0 
    global shipx
    global shipy
    global aliencounter
    global astroidY 
    global astroidY_change
    global enemy_y
    global alien
    global current_level
    global counter
    global bullets
    global spawner
    spawner=1
##    global livesr
    current_level=1
    direction= None
    running=True
    spawning=True

    bulletboost()
    while running:

        astroidY_change += .5
        #enemy_y += 0
        #global alienbullets
        for evt in event.get():
            if evt.type==QUIT:
                running=False
                quit()
            if evt.type==KEYDOWN:
                if evt.key == K_LEFT:
                    ship_x = -2.5
                if evt.key == K_RIGHT:
                    ship_x = 2.5
##                if evt.key == K_UP: 
##                    ship_y = -2
##                if evt.key == K_DOWN: 
##                    ship_y = 2
            if evt.type==KEYUP:
                if evt.key == K_LEFT or evt.key == K_RIGHT: 
                    ship_x = 0
##                    ship_y = 0

        shipx += ship_x
##        shipy += ship_y 

        if shipx <= 0: 
            shipx = 0
        elif shipx >= 900:
            shipx = 900

##        if shipy <= 0: 
##            shipy = 0
##        elif shipy >= 650:
##            shipy = 650



        # astroid Movement
        astroidY += astroidY_change

        if astroidY_change >=650: 
           astroidY_change =0    


        if rapidbullet<40:
            rapidbullet+=1

        keys=key.get_pressed()       
        if keys[32] and rapidbullet==40:#32 is the space key
            bullet_sound.play()

            bullets.append([shipx,shipy,v[0],v[1]]) 
            rapidbullet=0


        if random.randrange(0,6*30) == 1 and score_value<=10:
            aliencounter+=1
            x= randint(50,700)
            y= randint(0,100)
            alien.append([x,y])
            alienbullets.append([x,y,w[0],w[1]])


##        if random.randrange(0,6*40) == 1:
##            aliencounter+=1
##            x= randint(50,700)
##            y= randint(0,100)
##            alien.append([x,y])
##            alienbullets.append([x,y,w[0],w[1]])
##            if aliencounter==10:
##                function=False



        rel_y = y % bg_3.get_rect().width
        screen.blit(bg_3,(0,rel_y - bg_3.get_rect().width))
        if rel_y < 700:
            screen.blit(bg_3,(0,rel_y))
        y +=1

        if enemy_y >= 600: 
           enemy_y = 0
        for i in range(1):
            bulletboost()

        show_score(textx,texty)
        show_lives(10,70)
        show_level(10,10)
        moveBullets(bullets)
        move_alien_bull(alienbullets)
        checkHits(bullets,alien,asteroids,fastbullets)
        checkalienbullets(alienbullets)
        drawScene(screen,shipx,shipy,bullets,alienbullets,alien,asteroids) 
        display.update()
        myclock.tick(120)
        spawner+=1

    quit()




game_intro()
```

The problem is that when I run the game, it starts out smooth and then starts slowing down and becoming so slow that everything goes into slow motion. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Your fastbullets list is getting longer and longer. Perhaps you meant this:

```
def bulletboost():
    fasrbullets = [randint(50 ,800), (randint(0,100))]
    bul=image.load("image/bullet.png").convert()
    gameDisplay.blit(bul,(fastbullets[0],fastbullets[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue when I recreated the space invaders game. 
Try using convert_alpha() instead.

```
bul = image.load("image/bullet.png").convert_alpha()
```

https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.convert_alpha

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, that the image "image/bullet.png" is loaded in  every frame. Loading an image is a very time consuming operation. Load the image  once at the beginning of the program (somewhere after `display.set_mode`):

```py
gameDisplay = display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))

# [...]

bullet_image = image.load("image/bullet.png").convert_alpha()
```

And use the image in when you `blit` the bullet. But note, the bullet has not to be drawn when it spawns. You have to draw the bullets in the main application loop. Thus you need on function which appends a bullet and another function which draws a bullet:

```py
def spawnbullet():
    global fastbullets
    x = randint(50 ,800))
    y = randint(0,100))
    fastbullets.append((x, y))

def bulletboost():
    for pos in fastbullets:
        gameDisplay.blit(bullet_image, pos)
```

```py
def gameLoop():
    # [...]

    spawnbullet()
    while running:
        # [...]

        if enemy_y >= 600: 
            enemy_y = 0
        bulletboost()
```